# Can't propagate the Boolean object from angular client to the controller on the server side

Tags: c#, angular, controller

I have a problem where I am trying to send Boolean value from the angular client side to the c# controller on the server side.
The value I receive on the c# server side is always `false`.
My angular code looks like this:

```
Component code :
public onChangeHandler(event: any, tr: any) {
        this.accountService.setAutoEmail(new Boolean(event.target.checked))
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe({
                next: (autoEmail: any) => {
                    //tr.click();
                    this.autoEmail = autoEmail;
                },
                complete: () => {
                    //this.alertService.info("Done");
                },
                error: error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                }
            });
    }
```

... and account service code:

```
setAutoEmail(autoEmail: Boolean) {
        return this.http.put<Boolean>(`${baseUrl}/auto-email`, autoEmail);
    }
```

The c# server side controller handler looks like this:

```
[HttpPut("auto-email")]
        public ActionResult<Boolean> SetAutoEmail(Boolean autoEmail)
        {
            return Ok(_accountService.SetAutoEmail(autoEmail));
        }
```

I have checked on the client side in the browser `Network` tab that the body of the request contains the `true` value in the `Payload` tab.
However the server side value `autoEmail` is always `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It's binding problem and you should use `[FromBody]`